# The primitive type int of OutputType does not have a field FILE while using screenshot code

Tags: screenshot

hi i am using this code for screen shot but i am getting above error please help me if some one can thank you [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVgi5.png)
public static void takeScreen(String FilePath, String Value) {

```
    File ts=(File) ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(ts,new File(FilePath));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and was able to resolved by adding below to OutputType.FILE

File ts=(File) ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(org.openqa.selenium.OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(ts,new File(FilePath));